# What is the appropriate event listener for a page that change its content using XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, c#, webbrowser-control, geckofx

By using the GeckoWebBrowser in C# is there anyway to know when a page has completed updating its content using XMLHttpRequest ? I thought that the DocumentCompleted event would have done it but since the page it's not reloading it wont fire up...

Comment: *"...when a page has completed updating its content using XMLHttpRequest..."* `XMLHttpRequest` doesn't modify web pages. JavaScript code might, in response to the completion of an XHR request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) watching `document.body`'s subtree, and assume that the page has finished being modified (say) 20ms after the last notification you get.

In JavaScript, that would look something like this:

```js
(function() {
  var observer;

  // The click handler that appends content after a random delay
  document.querySelector('input').addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (!observer) {
       hookupObserver();
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
      var p = document.createElement('p');
      p.innerHTML = "New content added at " + Date.now();
      document.querySelector('div').appendChild(p);
    }, 500 + Math.round(Math.random() * 500));
  }, false);
  
  // Watching for subtree mods to `document.body`:
  function hookupObserver() {
    var timer = 0;
    observer = new MutationObserver(function() {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = setTimeout(done, 40);
    });
    observer.observe(document.body, {childList: true, subtree: true});
  }
  
  function done() {
    timer = 0;
    alert("Modification complete");
  }
})();
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Click to simulate async modification">
<div>This is the page</div>
```

Comment: It's just perfect... Thanks for the quick answer !

Comment: @MarcoDufal - Note: `MutationObserver` requires IE11 or above.

Comment: @jfriend00: He's using GeckoWebBrowser in C#. (But in IE9 and IE10, there are projects that emulate MutationObserver using -- ugh -- mutation events...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder In the cases the page it's mine or not this snippet works perfectly even if in the second case I have to append the snippet to the document programmatically... That's the first thing that I thought, but is there another way to avoid injecting code ?

Comment: @MarcoDufal: I don't understand the question.

Comment: I mean is there another way to use the observer without injecting code in pages that are not yours ?

Comment: @MarcoDufal: Not unless you can get a reference to their `document` object, which would require cross-origin scripting access, which would require cooperation from the site owner. You can only add a script element or use a [bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet).